# IE11 bugs in Dialogue and DropDown components

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

Will IE11 be supported with Kendo UI for Angular 2?  Here are a couple of bugs I'm seeing:

- Dialogue: content window is collapsed and doesn't expand when more content is present.  The problem exists on your demo page: http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dialog/
- DropDown: Auto complete and multi select do not allow text input.  The problem exists on your demo page:
  http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/

The dialogue component did work on a previous build, but now seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

We've logged the issues in the github repo. You can keep track of the progress in the following issues:

- Dialog - https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/192
- DropDown - https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/191

Thank you for reporting them.